# How put the data back after getting it from the stream?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting post data like this

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I want the data put back to the stream, so I modified the method following instaed of above method

```
$stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
stream_copy_to_stream(fopen('php://input', 'r'), $stream);
rewind($stream);
```

But it is not working. Can any one tell where I did wrong?
This case is need in wordpress plugin developement. If one plugin reads the post data, other plugin not able to get that data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), `php://input` can only be read once and doesn't support seek operations.

The only way to 'read' the input stream multiple times is through passing its copy in your program.

Comment: This case is need in wordpress plugin developement. If one plugin reads the post data, other plugin not able to get that data. we cant pass the copy .

Comment: In that case, you won't be able to use ```php://input```. I have no experience with wordpress, but I'm sure it must allow you to access the raw request data in some way, so I'd look that up. If it doesn't, you can always file an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

PHP input stream contains request body and your sample will work only if request will contain body.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"  -d 'sample body' "YOUR_ADDRESS"
```

For check add to code:

```
echo fgets($stream);
```

> php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php